# MethodImplOptions.Synchronized not working in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am using multiple threads to send serial port data to a robot.

When I call the navigate methods on `BotNavigation`, they do not synch with each other.

```
 SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3");
 BotNavigation bot = new BotNavigation();

 // must execute three times, but it only executes once.
 bot.TakeForward(3, port); 

 // must execute once, and it works fine.
 bot.TurnLeft(1, port);
```

Will you help me to solve the problem?

---

Here is the code...

```
namespace NavigateBot
{
    class BotNavigation
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public void TakeForward(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
        {
            int count = 0;
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    port.WriteLine("F");
                    if (count >= distanceTime)
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(distanceTime * 250);
                    count++;
                }
            }));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public void TakeBackward(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
        {
            int count = 0;
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    port.WriteLine("B");
                    if (count >= distanceTime)
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(distanceTime * 250);
                    count++;
                }
            }));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public void TurnLeft(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
        {
            int count = 0;
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    port.WriteLine("L");
                    if (count >= distanceTime)
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(distanceTime * 250);
                    count++;
                }
            }));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public void TurnRight(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
        {
            int count = 0;
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    port.WriteLine("R");
                    if (count >= distanceTime)
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(distanceTime * 250);
                    count++;
                }
            }));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do **NOT** call `Thread.Abort()` - see http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Comment: Your methods are synchronized, but they start extra threads, which don't synchronize on anything. Fundamentally, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but this doesn't look like the right approach...

Comment: @Enigmativity Calling abort in its own thread is safe. But I agree with you in general. In this case it is safe though.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I don't even think it is safe then. The only time it is safe is when you are closing your program.

Comment: @Enigmativity Why? Why do you think it is not safe when a thread aborts itself?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Why call `Abort()` when a  simple return is enough?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Read the article I linked to. It's all there.

Comment: TakeForward should executes for four times instead of three times as it starts from zero and ends on 3. Similar is true for TakeLeft which is probably TurnLeft, as there is not method TakeLeft in your posted code. This is the output I got, F
L
L
F
F
F

Comment: @jgauffin It is useful when you're not on top of the call stack. Let's say you're in a stackframe 5 levels deep. In that case Aborting current thread is an option rather than checking a flag in all of the methods.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: imho it's a weak design if something can decide if the thread should continue to run or not by using `Thread.Abort`. It should always be the decision of the entry point (***principle of least astonishment***). someone looking at all methods above the mentioned method would not expect the thread to get aborted.

Comment: @jgauffin Yes I do agree, and I anticipated this reply that it isn't a good design. I'm not advocating it is good, but it is safe to abort the thread by itself.

Comment: np. Was just interested to see if i've missed something.

Comment: I removed Thread.Abort(), I got partial result turnLeft() working but takeForward() not executed. Please give me suggestion...for working...

Answer (score 2):

You are synchronizing the methods using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` but these methods start their own threads to send the data to the serial port.

The actions that happen within the threads are not synchronized because the original method call (which started the thread) has already returned and released the lock created by `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`.

If you want the robot's actions to execute sequentially, you could synchronize the threads themselves on their own private lock object.

Further recommendations:

- There is no need to call `Thread.Abort()`, just use `count < distanceTime` as your `while` loop condition.
- You could use the thread pool to avoid the overhead of creating new threads yourself.

Like this:

```
namespace NavigateBot
{
    class BotNavigation
    {
        private readonly object _serialLock = new object();

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public void TakeForward(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
        {
            int count = 0;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            delegate
            {
                lock (_serialLock)
                {
                    while (count < distanceTime)
                    {
                        port.WriteLine("F");
                        Thread.Sleep(distanceTime*250);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        ...

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public void TurnLeft(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
        {
            int count = 0;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            delegate
            {
                lock (_serialLock)
                {
                    while (count < distanceTime)
                    {
                        port.WriteLine("L");
                        Thread.Sleep(distanceTime*250);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I was using Console.Out for debugging, rather than SerialPort. Try the updated code above.

Comment: You're welcome. If this has answer has solved your problem, you can thank me with rep points by accepting the answer and upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

To start with you do need to avoid `Thread.Abort()` like the plague. Rewriting one of your methods like this would be the easy way to avoid it:

```
    public void TakeBackward(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
    {
        int count = 0;
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                port.WriteLine("B");
                if (count >= distanceTime)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(distanceTime * 250);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
```

Having said that I'm going to suggest an alternative method to make this code work nicely for you.

I'm going to suggest that you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main").

Here's what the code would look like:

```
class BotNavigation
{
    private EventLoopScheduler _eventLoop = new EventLoopScheduler();

    private void Take(string message, int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
    {
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0))
            .Select(x => message)
            .StartWith(message)
            .Take(distanceTime)
            .ObserveOn(_eventLoop)
            .Subscribe(port.WriteLine);
    }

    public void TakeForward(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
    {
        this.Take("F", distanceTime, port);
    }

    public void TakeBackward(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
    {
        this.Take("B", distanceTime, port);
    }

    public void TurnLeft(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
    {
        this.Take("L", distanceTime, port);
    }

    public void TurnRight(int distanceTime, SerialPort port)
    {
        this.Take("R", distanceTime, port);
    }
}
```

The `EventLoopScheduler` is basically a background thread that will provide all of the synchronisation that you need.

The observable creates the timing and messages that you need.

```
        Observable
            // fire a timer every 250 ms
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0))
            // change the timer output to the message
            .Select(x => message)
            // at the start instantly output a message
            .StartWith(message)
            // only take `distanceTime` messages
            .Take(distanceTime)
            // execute the output on the synchronised event loop thread
            .ObserveOn(_eventLoop)
            // write the value to the port
            .Subscribe(port.WriteLine);
```

Hopefully this is fairly easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Thr synchronization attribute you use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` only synchronizes your methods but not the threads started in those methods.

When you call `botForward.TakeForward(3, port);` this blocks any pother thread from calling this method at the same time on the same BotNavigation instance, but this method runs pretty fast and it isn't even save to say that the internal thread of this method calls Port.Writeline even once before the method returns and the lock is released.

Furthermore your threads run with unprotected context variables in your current state: `SerialPort port` of all your threads works on the same instance of this class, which is unsafe as long as SerialPort itself isn't threadsafe.

The goal of your code is unclear to be, but you will probably be saver if you split the code into 2 threads: One which gives commands to your bot, and one single other thread that holds instances of your communication classes, and processes the commands in a deterministic manner (like a threadsafe queue)